# better design for Ajax replace div with another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am new to Ajax. I have a template which has "name" and a button. Wheni the button is clicked, the name and button will be replaced with some messages.
My code works perfectly. 
Ajax:

```
 $('#fulfillButton').bind('click',function() {
       $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url : "/order/${orderID}",
            dataType : "json",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 12000,

            success: function (data) {
                  alert("success");
            },

            error: function (data,textStatus) {
                if(textStatus == "timeout")
                {
                    $('#main-panel').replaceWith('<div class="error-message">' + "Timeout, please clcik the button beblow to scan again!" + '</div>');
                }
                else
                {
                    var responseText = data.responseText;
                    var jsonErrorMessage = JSON.parse(responseText);
                    $('#main-panel').replaceWith('<div class="error-message">' + jsonErrorMessage["body"] + '</div>');
                }
            },
       });
```

Html :

```
        <div id="main-panel">
        <div class="full-name">
            ${name}
        </div>
        <div id
        <button id="fulfillButton" type="button" class="action-button shadow animate fulfill-button-color">
            FulFill
        </button>
    </div>
    <button id="goBackButton" type="button" class="go-back-button">
        Go Back
    </button>
```

But now I am looking for a better design. As you can see

```
$('#main-panel').replaceWith('<div class="error-message">' + jsonErrorMessage["body"] + '</div>');
```

But I want to avoid interspersing view elements with the logic (to not put div tage here). I want to put DIV in the HTML or can I use the existing DIV with the "error_message" style applied in the JS? If so, how could I actually write code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add the error-message divs in your html (inside `main-panel`, give them some ids, lets say **error1**, **error2**) as 
hidden `<div class="error-message" id="someID' hidden>...</div>` and then when you get an error instead of `replace` just call

```
error: function (data,textStatus) {
    $('#main-panel').find('*').not('.error-message').remove();//Remove everything except from the error-message divs
    if(textStatus == "timeout")
    {
        $('#error1').html('Timeout, please clcik the button beblow to scan again!');
        $('#error1').show();
    }
    else
    {
        var responseText = data.responseText;
        var jsonErrorMessage = JSON.parse(responseText);
        $('#error2').html(jsonErrorMessage["body"]);
        $('#error2').show();
    }
},
```

Comment: I updated my answer with the given function  changed according to my suggestion.

Comment: can I actually just remove the whole '#main-panel' and create a new div (hidden) for the error message?

Comment: Sure, you can add the error divs outside `#main-panel` as hidden. Then, when an error occures call `$( '#main-panel').remove(); $('#error1').show();` Is this what you'd like?

Answer (score 1):

You can have many solutions. I give you two:

The first solution (See javascript) is good for small things (like your error message).

The second is good for lagger thing, such as creating a form dynamically. This is called templating.

```js
// Solution 1

$('#fulfillButton').bind('click',function() {
  $('#main-panel').replaceWith($('<div />').addClass('error-message').html('Some content here. This is added by dynamically creating the div, adding error message class and adding content'));       
});

// Solution 2
$('#fulfillButton2').bind('click',function() {
  $('#main-panel').replaceWith($("#error-message-template").clone().removeClass('hidden').html('Some content here 2. This is added by cloning an existing hidden div, removing the hidden class and replacing the content.'));       
});
```

```css
.error-message{
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

#main-panel{
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.hidden
{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-panel">
        <div class="full-name">
            ${name}
        </div>
        
        <button id="fulfillButton" type="button" class="action-button shadow animate fulfill-button-color">
          
            FulFill
        </button>
  <button id="fulfillButton2" type="button" class="action-button shadow animate fulfill-button-color">
    Fulfill 2
    </button>
    </div>
    <button id="goBackButton" type="button" class="go-back-button">
        Go Back
    </button>

<div id="error-message-template" class="error-message hidden">
</div>
```